# Changing the update terminal in Linux to US

Tags: linux

How can I change to US every time.I update in Linux terminal

the error:

```
: Failed to fetch http://ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/InRelease  
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-updates/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Failed to fetch http://ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-backports/Release.gpg  Could not resolve 'ph.nl.archive.ubuntu.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 1):

`$ sudo YOUR_FAVORITE_EDITOR /etc/apt/sources.list`, and change domain to `us.archive.ubuntu.com`